# How to manage freenom domain

Tags: dns

I registered a domain (yezhiyi.tk) on freenom, but I don't know how to manage files in it.
Someone says FTP, but no use.
[Image: FTP is no use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e4As.png)

I also tried to enter yezhiyi.tk/admin.phph?, but no use.
I tried to design it on GoSite, it works.
[Image: It works with GoSite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRPi4.png)
Is it possible to manage it without GoSite?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access it without GoSite by signing up into a free web hosting service like [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com) or [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.in/). You can search on how to use those.

Comment: 000webhost creats  a new subdomain for me. How can I manage my own domain?

Comment: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-point-domain-from-freenom-com-to-000webhost-com/36763